# How can I find the book with the highest price written after 2000?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

My task is to find out which book has the highest price written after 2000 and the output should be the Book

Here is the data (only the part where the books are defined is important^^):

```
static public class SampleData
  {
    static public Publisher[] Publishers =
    {
      new Publisher {Name="FunBooks"},
      new Publisher {Name="Joe Publishing"},
      new Publisher {Name="I Publisher"}
    };

    static public Author[] Authors =
    {
      new Author {FirstName="Johnny", LastName="Good"},
      new Author {FirstName="Graziella", LastName="Simplegame"},
      new Author {FirstName="Octavio", LastName="Prince"},
      new Author {FirstName="Jeremy", LastName="Legrand"}
    };

    static public Subject[] Subjects =
    {
      new Subject {Name="Software development",Description="developing and others"},
      new Subject {Name="Novel",Description="great feelings"},
      new Subject {Name="Science fiction",Description="out of space and everywhere"}
    };

    static public Book[] Books =
    {
      new Book {                                        // [0]
        Title="Funny Stories",
        Publisher=Publishers[0],
        Authors=new[]{Authors[0], Authors[1]},
        PageCount=101,
        Price=25.55M,
        PublicationDate=new DateTime(2004, 11, 10),
        Isbn="0-000-77777-2",
        Subject=Subjects[0]
      },
      new Book {                                        // [1]
        Title="LINQ rules",
        Publisher=Publishers[1],
        Authors=new[]{Authors[2]},
        PageCount=300,
        Price=12M,
        PublicationDate=new DateTime(2007, 9, 2),
        Isbn="0-111-77777-2",
        Subject=Subjects[0]
      },
      new Book {                                        // [2]
        Title="C# on Rails",
        Publisher=Publishers[1],
        Authors=new[]{Authors[2]},
        PageCount=256,
        Price=35.5M,
        PublicationDate=new DateTime(2007, 4, 1),
        Isbn="0-222-77777-2",
        Subject=Subjects[0]
      },
      new Book {                                        // [3]
        Title="All your base are belong to us",
        Publisher=Publishers[1],
        Authors=new[]{Authors[3]},
        PageCount=1205,
        Price=35.5M,
        PublicationDate=new DateTime(2006, 5, 5),
        Isbn="0-333-77777-2",
        Subject=Subjects[2]
      },
      new Book {                                        // [4]
        Title="Bonjour mon Amour",
        Publisher=Publishers[0],
        Authors=new[]{Authors[1], Authors[2]},
        PageCount=50,
        Price=29M,
        PublicationDate=new DateTime(1973, 2, 18),
        Isbn="2-444-77777-2",
        Subject=Subjects[1]
      }
    };

    static public User[] Users = 
    {
        new User{Name="Fred"},
        new User{Name="Barney"},
        new User{Name="Wilma"}
    };

    static public Review[] Reviews =
    {
        new Review{ Book = Books[0], Comments="cc1", Rating=2, User=Users[0]},
        new Review{ Book = Books[0], Comments="cc2", Rating=3, User=Users[2]},
        new Review{ Book = Books[1], Comments="cc3", Rating=1, User=Users[0]},
        new Review{ Book = Books[1], Comments="cc4", Rating=2, User=Users[1]},
        new Review{ Book = Books[1], Comments="cc5", Rating=1, User=Users[2]},
        new Review{ Book = Books[2], Comments="cc6", Rating=3, User=Users[2]},        
        new Review{ Book = Books[3], Comments="cc7", Rating=4, User=Users[2]},
        new Review{ Book = Books[4], Comments="cc8", Rating=5, User=Users[1]}
    };

    static SampleData()
    {
        // Books -- Reviews haben einnen Doppelverweise
        //          daher kann erst hier  Book-->Review gesetzt werden
        Books[0].Reviews = new[] { Reviews[0], Reviews[1] };
        Books[1].Reviews = new[] { Reviews[2], Reviews[3], Reviews[4] };
        Books[2].Reviews = new[] { Reviews[5] };
        Books[3].Reviews = new[] { Reviews[6] };
        Books[4].Reviews = new[] { Reviews[7] };
    }

  }
```

Here is what I've written:

```
var query3 =
            (from buch in SampleData.Books
             where buch.PublicationDate.Year > 2000
             select buch.Price).ToList();
        decimal ergebnis3 = query3.Max();

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------Aufgabe 3-------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Ermitteln sie das Buch mit dem größten Preis welches nach 2000 geschrieben wurde. Ausgabe ist das Buch:");
        ObjectDumper.Write(ergebnis3);
```

How can I bring price and title together and find out the book with the highest price written after 2000?

Comment: Hope you don't mind but I have edited your title.  Titles like _"How can I bring these two together"_ might not be very informative to people browsing SO or those using Google search in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much for the correction ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Off topic: Addition after comment about sorting at the end**

As your class SampleData already has a property Books, the query is fairly simple:

```
Book mostExpensiveBookAfter2000 = SampleData.Books
    .Where(book => book.PublicationDate.Year > 2000)
    .OrderByDescending(book => book.Price)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

In words: from all `Books` in `SampleData` keep only those Books that have a value for `PublicationDate.Year` larger than 2000. Order the remaining Books by descending `Price`. This way the most expensive Book will be the first one. Finally take the first one, or null if there are no Books left.

Although this solution is easy to understand, if you only want the most expensive Book, it would be a bit of waste of processing power to sort all Books.

Consider to use [Enumerable.Aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-5.0). Initialize the first Book as the most expensive one. In every Aggregation step compare the price of the most expensive Book with the price of the next Book, and keep the most expensive one.

```
Book mostExpensiveBookAfter2000 = SampleData.Books
    .Where(book => book.PublicationDate.Year > 2000)
    .Aggregate( (mostExpensiveBook, nextBook) =>
         (nextBook.Price > mostExpensiveBook.Price) ?  // is nextBook more expensive?
             nextBook :                          // if so, nextBook becomes mostExpensiveBook
             mostExpensiveBook);                 // if not, keep mostExpensiveBook
```

This way you will only enumerate the sequence once.

### Is OrderBy efficient?

Will OrderBy sort the complete sequence if you only take the first element or will it only enumerate the sequence once?

For this we look at the [reference source of class Enumerable](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L2559)

Method OrderBy only creates an object of OrderedEnumerable:

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    return new OrderedEnumerable<TSource, TKey>(source, keySelector,
       null, false);
}
```

This OrderedEnumerale doesn't do a lot, until you start enumerating. The first step in enumerating is getting the enumerator:

```
 public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator()
 {
     Buffer<TElement> buffer = new Buffer<TElement>(source);
     if (buffer.count > 0)
     {
         EnumerableSorter<TElement> sorter = GetEnumerableSorter(null);
         int[] map = sorter.Sort(buffer.items, buffer.count);
         sorter = null;

         for (int i = 0; i < buffer.count; i++)
         {
             yield return buffer.items[map[i]];
         }
    }
}
```

So it puts the complete source in a Buffer, and it ask the enumerable sorter to sort the data in the Buffer:

```
internal int[] Sort(TElement[] elements, int count)
{
    ComputeKeys(elements, count);
    int[] map = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) map[i] = i;

    QuickSort(map, 0, count - 1);
    return map;
}

void QuickSort(int[] map, int left, int right)
{
    do
    {
        int i = left;
        int j = right;
        int x = map[i + ((j - i) >> 1)];
        do
        {
            while (i < map.Length && CompareKeys(x, map[i]) > 0) i++;
            while (j >= 0 && CompareKeys(x, map[j]) < 0) j--;
            if (i > j) break;
            if (i < j)
            {
                int temp = map[i];
                map[i] = map[j];
                map[j] = temp;
            }
            i++;
            j--;
        } while (i <= j);
        if (j - left <= right - i) {
        if (left < j) QuickSort(map, left, j);
        left = i;
    }
    else
    {
        if (i < right) QuickSort(map, i, right);
        right = j;
    }
} while (left < right);
```

So it seems that if you only ask for the enumerator, the complete sequence will be sorted, even before you do your first `MoveNext()`.

### Use the debugger to check this

You can check this if you create your own IComparer:

```
public class MyComparer : Comparer<int>
{
    private IComparer<int> comparer = Comparer<int>.Default;
    public override int Compare (int x, int y)
    {
        return this.comparer.Compare(x, y);
        // put your breakpoint here
    }
}

IEnumerable<int> values = new int[] {8, 5, 6, 10, 2, 4 };
IEnumerable<int> orderedValues = values.OrderBy(i => i, new MyComparer());

var enumerator = orderedValues.GetEnumerator();
// if you have a breakpoint in the code above, you see that Compare is called
// many times, before you starte enumerating.

// the compare is not used anymore while you enumerate:
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    int i = enumerator.Current;
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: "_it would be a bit of waste of processing power to sort all Books_" The first example only requires one iteration as well. `Where` yields each item as it is iterated by `OrderByDescending`, and of course `FirstOrDefault` is an `O(1)` operation when no delegate is provided.

Answer (score 4):

```
var bookWithHighestPriceAfter2000 = SampleData.Books
    .Where(x => x.PublicationDate.Year > 2000) // Filter books published after 2000
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Price) // Order by price; highest first
    .First(); // Take the first book
```

If it's possible that there may be no books published after 2000, you may want to replace `First` with `FirstOrDefault`, which will return `null` rather than throwing an exception.

Answer (score 1):

This is working solution for you:

```
  var result = Books.Where(x => x.PublicationDate.Year > 2000).OrderByDescending(x => x.Price).First();
```